# How to add animation when modal shown

Tags: nativescript

I trying add in animation slide right to left when modal page show, but when I adding will get error, isn't can add animation when open modal page?

```
exports.onModalClick = function(args){

    var btn = args.object;

    page.showModal("views/abc/Modal/Modal", "abc", function (List) {
        if(List.length != 0){
        }
    }, false).animation({ translate: { x: 0, y: 0 }, opacity: 1 });
};
```

Comment: Can you please paste what kind of error you are getting?

Comment: Error : Cannot read property 'animation' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out a few things.

1. The method for animating a view is

   `public animate(options: animation.AnimationDefinition): Promise<void>;`

and it is an instance function of the View class. Thus your scenario will not work, since the `showModal` method does not return an instance of the class View. More information about it could be found in the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/core/view/View.html) and in the [NativeScript GitHub repository](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/ui/core/view.d.ts#L453).

2. In order to attach several animations you will have to chain them and not include them in one object. You can read more about this in the [Animation article](https://docs.nativescript.org/animation.html#chaining-with-animation-set) in the documentation.

I hope this will give you some directions of how to use the animation in NativeScript.